# Import controller and view to web project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

I want to create a code library that has a controller (FooController) and an accompanying view (Foo.cshtml) and import it to a web project. The idea is to create a nuget package out of this project so that it can be imported to other web projects. But when I test to import this project in another web project and navigate to the controller, the controller hits, but I get a view engine exception when it tries to load the view. Any ideas on if this is possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Because on default it only loads controllers out of the main dll/project.

You can extend/overwrite this part of code (from .Net MVC) that discovers the controllers: the [ControllerFactory](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/732449/Understanding-and-Extending-Controller-Factory-i)

The router matches url for a route and tells the ControllerFactory the name of the controller it wants.

This controllerFactory on default only reflects your Startup DLL (code project) and not external nuget packages.